# If and how can I install a ktor plugin locally within a route for GET but not for POST?

Tags: kotlin, authorization, ktor

For a ktor (2.0.3) application (kotlin 1.7.10) I want to have two endpoints on the same route (*/feedback*) but with different http methods, one GET and one POST.

So far no problem.

Now I would like to install an *AuthorizationPlugin* on only one of them.
I know how to install a plugin for a specific route only, but is it also possible to separately install it for different http methods on the same route?

So far I could not figure out a solution that does not require me to either introduce different routes (e.g. /feedback/read, /feedback/new) or handle the authorization check within the GET and POST callbacks directly.

The following is a reduced code containing two tests demonstrating the problem.

```kotlin
package some.example.package

import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.auth.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.testing.*
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException
import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

internal enum class AuthRole {
    Admin, User
}

@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
internal data class AuthUserSession(val username: String, val roles: Set<AuthRole> = setOf()) : Principal

const val authName = "form-auth"
const val usernameFormField = "username"
const val passwordFormField = "password"



/**
 * Plugin Implementation
 */

internal val AuthorizationPlugin = createRouteScopedPlugin(
    name = "AuthorizationPlugin",
    createConfiguration = ::RoleBaseConfiguration
) {
    pluginConfig.apply {
        on(AuthenticationChecked) { call ->
            val principal =
                call.authentication.principal<AuthUserSession>() ?: throw Exception("Missing principal")
            val userRoles = principal.roles
            val denyReasons = mutableListOf<String>()
            roles?.let {
                if (roles!!.none { it in userRoles }) {
                    denyReasons += "Principal $principal has none of the sufficient role(s) ${
                        roles!!.joinToString(
                            " or "
                        )
                    }"
                }
            }
            if (denyReasons.isNotEmpty()) {
                val message = denyReasons.joinToString(". ")
                throw Exception(message)
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class RoleBaseConfiguration (
    var roles: Set<AuthRole>? = null,
)



/**
 * Server setup
 */

internal fun Application.setupConfig() {
    install(Authentication) {
        form(authName) {
            userParamName = usernameFormField
            passwordParamName = passwordFormField
            challenge {
                throw AuthenticationException()
            }
            validate { cred: UserPasswordCredential ->
                if (cred.name == AuthRole.Admin.name) {
                    AuthUserSession(username = "admin", roles = setOf(AuthRole.Admin))
                } else {
                    AuthUserSession(username = "user", roles = setOf(AuthRole.User))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    routing {
        route("feedback") {
            authenticate(authName) {
                post {
                    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Created, "Submitting feedback")
                }

                install(AuthorizationPlugin) {
                    roles = setOf(AuthRole.Admin)
                }
                get {
                    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Getting feedback")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



/**
 * Tests
 */

internal class PluginIssueTest {
    /**
     * For a valid solution this test should succeed.
     */
    @Test
    fun testGiveFeedback() = testApplication {
        application {
            setupConfig()
        }
        client.post("/feedback") {
            header(HttpHeaders.ContentType, ContentType.Application.FormUrlEncoded.toString())
            setBody(
                listOf(
                    usernameFormField to AuthRole.User.name,
                    passwordFormField to "mypassword"
                ).formUrlEncode()
            )
        }.apply {
            assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.Created, status)
        }
    }

    /**
     * For this test the plugin is successfully called and required role is checked.
     */
    @Test
    fun testReadFeedback() = testApplication {
        application {
            setupConfig()
        }
        client.get("/feedback") {
            header(HttpHeaders.ContentType, ContentType.Application.FormUrlEncoded.toString())
            setBody(
                listOf(
                    usernameFormField to AuthRole.Admin.name,
                    passwordFormField to "mypassword"
                ).formUrlEncode()
            )
        }.apply {
            assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, status)
        }
    }
}
```

I made most of the things `internal` so they would not interfere with the implementations for my actual application. It should not have any influence on the tests.

Suggestions are highly appreciated.

If I forgot some important information please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I took a closer look at the implementation of [`authenticate`](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/258bf038e1b977afadaf61c159e5f8448d66d413/ktor-server/ktor-server-plugins/ktor-server-auth/jvmAndNix/src/io/ktor/server/auth/AuthenticationInterceptors.kt#L151-L172) and found a solution there.

It uses the `createChild` of the `Route` class with a custom `RouteSelector` that always evaluates to a "transparent" quality, to define a specific route for the authentication.
Since I currently only need a single RouteSelector instance I simplified it to be an object instead of a class.

By adding the following implementation to my code...

```kotlin
fun Route.authorize(
    roles: Set<AuthRole>,
    build: Route.() -> Unit
): Route {
    val authenticatedRoute = createChild(AuthorizationRouteSelector)
    authenticatedRoute.install(AuthorizationPlugin) {
        this.roles = roles
    }
    authenticatedRoute.build()
    return authenticatedRoute
}

object AuthorizationRouteSelector : RouteSelector() {
    override fun evaluate(context: RoutingResolveContext, segmentIndex: Int): RouteSelectorEvaluation {
        return RouteSelectorEvaluation.Transparent
    }

    override fun toString(): String = "(authorize \"default\" )"
}
```

...I was able to use my authorization plugin as follows:

```kotlin
routing {
        route("feedback") {
            authenticate(authName) {
                post {
                    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Created, "Submitting feedback")
                }
                authorize(setOf(AuthRole.Admin)) {
                    get {
                        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Getting feedback")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

making both tests succeed.